# Overriding @timestamp via Logstash's date filter with a grok-extracted value

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I am trying to mutate an string value to date time in logstash. Although the format is correct but in kibana/elastic search the field is showing string and not date.

As part of the analysis I tried to mutate the date in multiple ways but none of them are working. I tried some filters for milliseconds and half day as the date format for my log is with AM/PM.

Grok

```
match => { message => [
"\"%{WORD:status}\"\,\"(?<monitortime>%{MONTH:month}%{SPACE}%{MONTHDAY:day}\,%{SPACE}%{YEAR:year}%{SPACE}%{TIME:t1}%{SPACE}%{WORD:t2})\"\,\"%{WORD:monitor}\"\,%{INT:loadtime}\,%{INT:totalbytes}\,\"%{WORD:location}\"\,(?m)%{GREEDYDATA:error}"
```

Date Conversion

```
date {
        locale => "en"
        match => [ "monitortime", "MMM dd, yyyy kk:mm:ss.SSS aa ZZZ", "YYYY-MM-dd kk:mm:ss.SSS aa ZZZ" ]
        timezone => "Etc/UCT"
        }
```

output in kibana

```
message "Error","Jun 14, 2019 02:47:33 pm","xxxxxxxxxx",0,0,"stage_1","HomePage: Sign in link is not visible!"

monitortime Jun 14, 2019 02:47:33 pm

monitortime  string


Timestamp recorded by elasticsearch 
 @timestamp Sep 10, 2019 @ 20:06:48.525
```

The expected result will be to get monitortime as datatype date.

Comment: Is your event tagged with "_dateparsefailure" ?

Comment: And why do you define the time zone offset/id (ZZZ) in your patterns when there is none in the sample data?

Comment: Yes event tagged with "_dateparsefailure". Also let me try removing ZZZ

Comment: "tags" => [
        [0] "monitor",
        [1] "_dateparsefailure"

Comment: So this means that the date filter plugin failed, meaning that it could not match the data (value of monitortime) against the provided patterns. Try the patterns without the  ime zone offset/id (ZZZ) (see above comment)

Comment: Changed the conversion
date {
        locale => "en"
        match => [ "monitortime", "MMM dd, yyyy KK:mm:ss aa" ]
   }

Still I am getting the date in string format and dateparsefaliure

Comment: As you suggested to remove ZZZ i did the same and re-executed the configuration file. The result is same i am still getting monitortime as string and not datetime and also i am getting dateparsefaliure.

Comment: Try **MMM dd, yyyy KK:mm:ss a**. The *halfday of day* should be specified with only one 'a' in my opinion.

Comment: I changed to as you suggested still the error persists 
t monitortime Jun 01, 2019 12:01:09 am => t is string in kibana
tags monitor, _dateparsefailure

date {
        locale => "en"
        match => [ "monitortime", "MMM dd, yyyy KK:mm:ss a" ]
   }

Comment: Comment out the locale setting and try again please.

Comment: I commented the locale , but still the i am getting t tags monitor, _dateparsefailure in kibana and also date is still in string format.

Comment: Any further input?